# How do I decompress multiple files from a MemoryStream

Tags: c#, asp.net, gzip

I am downloading a compressed file and decompressing it with the following code:

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 MemoryStream download = new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData(targetUrl));
 var data = new GZipStream(download, CompressionMode.Decompress, true);
```

From here, how do I see the files within the compressed archive and sort through them? I know that one of the files in this archive is the one I need based on its file type (.csv) and I need to take it out. How can this be done through c#?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2006/05/10/592551.aspx

Comment: what kind of information is in gzipstream?

Comment: The archive contains three compressed files, I'm interested in only one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GZipStream is used to compress and decompress a stream...you cannot use it to compress and decompress multiple files. Actually, you can, but you should develop some way of merging those files into one stream and also know how to make the operation reverse (get those files from stream). If you have a single file, you would do it like this:

```
using (var outFile = File.Create(outputFileName))
{
    using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(download, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        var buffer = new byte[4096];
        var numRead = 0;
        while ((numRead = gzip.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            outFile.Write(buffer, 0, numRead);
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](http://www.vwd-cms.com/Forum/Forums.aspx?topic=18) is an article describing how GZipStream can be used to compress/decompress multiple files, but as you can see, the author developed his own "zip" format for storing multiple files, and individual streams are compressed using GZipStream.

In your case, if you didn't do that compression, you are most likely receiving standard zip file, and in that case you can use library called [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) to decompress your content.

Here is an example using SharpZipLib

```
using (var s = new ZipInputStream(download))
{
    ZipEntry theEntry;
    while ((theEntry = s.GetNextEntry()) != null) 
    {
        string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(theEntry.Name);
        string fileName      = Path.GetFileName(theEntry.Name);
        
        if(fileName == myFileName)
        {
            using (FileStream streamWriter = File.Create(theEntry.Name)) 
            {
                int size = 2048;
                byte[] data = new byte[2048];
                while (true) 
                {
                    size = s.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    if (size > 0) 
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write(data, 0, size);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there somethign else apart from GZipStream that I can use to decompress my archive and access the file I need?

Answer (score 0):

Are you pulling a ZIP file from somewhere and trying to get a single file out of the archive?

You can you the ZipPackage class to do that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage.aspx

See GetPart Method specifically for example code:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.package.getpart.aspx